# angularjs factory is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have the following `userModule`:

```
(function () {
var userModule = angular.module('user', [
    'Auth'
]);

userModule.controller('UserController', ['$http', '$scope', function (UserFactory) {
    var uc = this;
    uc.user ={}; //set when login

    uc.login = login;

    function login(username, password)
    {
        UserFactory.login(username,password).then(function success(reponse){
            uc.user = reponse.data
        })
    }
}]);

userModule.factory('UserFactory', function UserFactory ($http)
{
    'use strict';
    return{
        login: login
    };
    function login(username, password)
    {
        return $http.post(API_URL + '/login',
            {
                username: username,
                password: password
            });
    }

});

})();
```

Now when i call the login function i get an error telling me that `UserFactory is undefined`

Can anyone tell me what ive done wrong?

**MY Form**

```
        <form class="panel-body wrapper-lg" ng-controller="UserController as userCtrl"
          ng-submit="userCtrl.login(userCtrl.user.username, userCtrl.user.password)" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Brugernavn</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="txt_username" name="username"
                   placeholder="Brugernavn" ng-model="userCtrl.user.username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Kodeord</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Kodeord" class="form-control input-lg"
                   ng-required="" ng-model="userCtrl.user.password">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lb-primary" value="Log på">

    </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When defining the controller using an array as the second argument, you're really just telling the angular dependency injection engine what to inject in the function/closure that comes as the last argument. Therefore, you'll have to tell it explicitly to inject UserFactory. In your case, the UserFactory in your controller closure would be an instance of the `$http` service.

```
userModule.controller('UserController', ['$http', '$scope', 'UserFactory', function ($http, $scope, UserFactory) {
    var uc = this;
    uc.user ={}; //set when login

    uc.login = login;

    function login(username, password)
    {
        UserFactory.login(username,password).then(function success(reponse){
            uc.user = reponse.data
        })
    }
}]);
```

Although I'm not sure it makes any difference, I like to declare my modules, services, etc. in the a chronological order, i.e. create your `userModule` first, then make your `UserFactory`, and lastly your controller.

As an idea for optimization, try and use the same syntax for your factory as your controller:

```
userModule.factory('UserFactory', ['$http', function UserFactory ($http)
{
    //....
}]);
```

The reason why the array syntax is used is that when you minify your js, your local variables would have some name that isn't resolvable to a service because angulars dependency injector cannot read the variable name, ultimately looking something like:

```
userModule.factory('UserFactory', ['$http', function UserFactory (t)
{
    //....
}]);
```

Comment: This still gives me undefined however i think its the login function that is undefined

Comment: Your idea for optimizing gives me an error saying that it couldnt load the module

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Where're you calling your login function? If you do it from a directive, ie from `ngClick` f.x., you have to define it as an attribute on the scope. `$scope.login = login;`.

Comment: @Dencker ive posted my form

Comment: Marc - try injecting the `$log` service and in your controller fire `$log.log(UserFactory)`.